# HBase: MiniDFSCluster.java Fails in Certain Environments

Tags: java, unit-testing, hadoop, nullpointerexception, hbase

I'm working on some code to access HBase and I am writing unit tests that create a MiniDFSCluster as part of the test setup.

```
(defn test-config [& options]
    (let [testing-utility (HBaseTestingUtility.)]
        (.startMiniCluster testing-utility 1)
        (let [config (.getConfiguration testing-utility)]
            (if (not= options nil)
                (doseq [[key value] options]
                    (.set config key value)))
            config)))

;; For those who don't read Clojure, lines 2 and 3 cause 
;; the failure and are equivalent to the following Java
;; 
;; HBaseTestingUtility testingUtility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
;; testingUtility.startMiniCluster(1);  // blows up on Linux but not Mac OSX
```

This runs fine on Mac OSX with Java HotSpot:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)

$ lein test

lein test hbase.config-test

lein test hbase.table-test
2013-07-12 17:44:13.488 java[27384:1203] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
Starting DataNode 0 with dfs.data.dir: /Users/dwilliams/Desktop/Repos/mobiusinversion/hbase/target/test-data/fe0199fd-0168-48d9-98ce-b4a5e62d3257/dfscluster_bbad1095-58d1-4571-ba12-4d4f1c24203f/dfs/data/data1,/Users/dwilliams/Desktop/Repos/mobiusinversion/hbase/target/test-data/fe0199fd-0168-48d9-98ce-b4a5e62d3257/dfscluster_bbad1095-58d1-4571-ba12-4d4f1c24203f/dfs/data/data2
Cluster is active

Ran 11 tests containing 14 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

But when this is run in a Linux environment, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR in (create-table) (MiniDFSCluster.java:426)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.startDataNodes (MiniDFSCluster.java:426)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init> (MiniDFSCluster.java:284)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniDFSCluster (HBaseTestingUtility.java:444)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster (HBaseTestingUtility.java:612)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster (HBaseTestingUtility.java:568)
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster (HBaseTestingUtility.java:555)
```

I filed a travis-ci ticket, since this first manifested itself there and I thought it might be due to their environment.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1240

However, after discussion with travis support I was able to reproduce the error on CentOS. I tried both the Sun JDK and the OpenJDK on Linux and both produced the same error.  Whats going on here?  Is this a trivial configuration problem?  Perhaps something not set in the Linux ENV that is set in Mac OSX's ENV?

If you would like to run the tests, please clone the repo

https://github.com/mobiusinversion/hbase

And run lein test. Help is greatly appreciated!

Update:

Filed this HBASE Jira ticket

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8944

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: set "`umask 022`" prior to running the tests.

Long answer: This is a common environmental issue with running MiniDFSCluster from Hadoop 1.x, releases, which HBaseTestingUtility uses internally.  It has been effectively fixed in Hadoop 0.22+ (including 2.0+, but not 1.x at the moment).

The underlying problem is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2556.

When the MiniDFSCluster starts up, it creates the temporary storage directories to use for the datanode processes (configured as "dfs.data.dir").  These will be created with your currently set umask.  When each datanode starts up, it checks that the directories configured in "dfs.data.dir" both exist and that the directory permissions match the expected value (set as "dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm").  If the directories permissions do not match the expected value ("755" by default), then the datanode process exits.

By default, in Hadoop 1.x, this value is set to "755", so if you set your umask to "022", the data directories will wind up with the correct permissions.  If however, the permissions do not match the expected value, the datanode will abort and you will see errors like the following in the test log file:

```
WARN  [main] datanode.DataNode(1577): Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: Incorrect permission for /.../dfs/data/data2, expected: rwxr-xr-x, while actual: rwxrwxr-x
```

In later versions of Hadoop, the datanode will attempt to change the directory permissions to the expected value if they do not match.  Only if this operation fails will the datanode abort.  HDFS-2556 proposes backporting this change to the 1.x releases, but has not yet been fixed.